# Bash read and stderr redirection

Tags: bash, redirect

So I've got a script that runs test cases on another script.  I'm trying to redirect stderr while running the test cases.  The part that is giving me problems is the read command:

within script1:

```
read -p "Delete $file? (y/n) " input
```

within testscript:

```
$script $opts $file 2>/dev/null
```

The read calls from script1 get redirected as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redirect the prompt to stdout.

```
read -p "Delete $file? (y/n) " input 2>&1
```

Comment: Why would the read calls be sent to stderr in the first place?

Comment: That's how it's documented in my bash man page: `-p prompt:  Display prompt on standard error [...]`

Comment: > Why would the read calls be sent to stderr in the first place? ... I would call printing the prompt to stderr a feature. If you only have 2 streams to use, stdout and stderr, you want your real data to go to stdout, so that only leaves stderr for non-data information to be passed on. (that is to say, stderr can be used for other information flows besides error messages) ... Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can go simple:

```
echo "Delete $file? (y/n)"
read input
```